# the new docker cli compose command shutting down the containers when closing the bash window

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The new docker cli compose command shutting down the containers when closing the bash window.

As we all noticed, docker cli recommends to use the "docker compose " command instead of the old docker-compose utility (They imbedded the docker-compose fluxionality into the docker cli).

The problem is that when I am following the recommendation, docker cli recognize that I'm closing the bash window and it shutting down all the containers. with the old docker-compose it's not like that and the containers keeps running.

I know that theoretically I can detach the process by CTRL+P, CTRL+Q but it doesn't work also.

Any ideas how to be able close the bash window without shutting down the containers? I'm not talking about CTRL+C which usually stopping the containers. just closing the bash window by clicking on the X sign on the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-d` flag to make the containers run in detached mode. For example:

```
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: -d detaching immediately. I want to keep seeing the logs and to be able to close the bash window when i want but without auto stopping the containers.

Comment: Then use `-d` when running the container, and then `docker attach container_name` to attach your shell to the container's output. You could also check the container's output periodically with `docker logs container_name`.